# Loop infinito ao caminhar recursivamente pelos nodos do DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma `div` com `contenteditable=true` no meu documento e pretendo fazer *highlight* em certas partes do texto enquanto o usuário digita (adicionar spans). Para tal preciso primeiro extrair o texto digitado pelo usuário na forma de uma string simples, sem tags, e preservando quebras de linha. Dessa forma `<p>aa</p><p>bb</p>` geraria `"aa\nbb"` e `<div>aaa</div><div><br></div>` geraria `"aaa\n"`. Para tal criei uma função que é chamada no `oninput` da div e que deveria retornar um array com cada linha de texto (`["aa", "bb"]` e `["aaa", ""]` para os exemplos acima).

Inicialmente fiz focando apenas no chrome. Ele cria o conteúdo da div conforme o usuário digita produzindo divs internas para cada linha. Em alguns casos divs podem ser geradas uma dentro da outra. Ex: (identação foi adicionada para legibilidade)

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
  primeira linha
  <div>segunda linha</div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div>
    quarta linha
    <div>quinta linha</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiz o seguinte código para obter a array resultante:

```js
function extractLines(elem) {
    var nodes = elem.childNodes;
    var lines = [];
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        if (node.nodeName == "#text") {
            lines.push(node.nodeValue);
        }
        else if (node.nodeName == "BR") {
            lines.push("");
        }
        else { // DIV ou P
            lines.push.apply(lines, extractLines(node));
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

A ideia é bastante simples:

- Para cada subnodo da div:

  1. Se for um nodo de texto, é uma linha. Inclua na array.
  2. Se for um `<br>`, é uma linha em branco. Inclua `""` na array.
  3. Se for um `<div>` ou `<p>`, execute recursivamente esse algoritmo e insira o resultado no fim da array.

Mas esse mesmo código gera um loop sem fim em alguns dos meus testes, não entendo o motivo.

- `<div>aa<div><br></div></div>` => `["aa", ""]`
- `<div>aa<div><br></div><div><br></div></div>` => loop infinito

**Por que** esse loop infinito acontece? Há algo errado no meu código? Como implementar esse mesmo algoritmo sem esse problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gastei uns bons minutos depurando o código num fiddle, até perceber uma nuance muito, muito sutil.

A variável de controle do seu laço `for` está declarada como uma variável global sem o `var`, logo ela está ficando com "sujeira" a cada recursão.

Altere o código da seguinte forma:

```js
...
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
...
```

Comment: haha me "bateu" por 13 segundos... :P

Comment: terei que aceitar pelos 13 segundos.. Funcionou!

Comment: Essa foi a situação mais curiosa que já vi... :)

Comment: Eu também estava olhando e deixei passar a falta do `var`, estava perplexo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Perplexo².

Comment: Eu fiquei perprecto! =D

Answer (score 7):

Você se esqueceu de declarar a variável `i` usando `var`, o que fez com que ela se tornasse uma global. A chamada recursiva sobrescreve seu valor, de modo que quando ela retorna ele itera de novo sobre elementos já existentes (entrando na recursão de novo e voltando de novo).

Acrescente o `var` e a função ficará correta:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
```

Comment: +1 por uma solução genial... ;)